# Django filter objects foreign key from another table

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Two tables: post and rating.

**rating** contains column - *post* (FK) that is **post** table's primary ID.
I'm trying to filter table **rating** by columns *user* and *ratingtype* to get *post* (FK) value that I could use to filter post table by.

```
Post.objects.filter(pk__in=Rating.objects.get(post=post).filter(Rating.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, ratingtype='like')))
```

Comment: So you want all `Post` objects with a like from a given user?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look "*through*" relations with two consecutive underscores (`__`), so:

```
Post.objects.filter(
    rating__user=self.request.user,
    rating__ratingtype='like'
).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) clause prevents returing the same `Post` multiple times if the user has given multiple ratings.

If you specified a [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) or [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the `ForeignKey`, then that is the name of the relation in reverse, so then instead of `rating__` it is `related_query_name__` (with *`related_query_name`* the *value* you used for the `related_query_name=…` parameter).

Comment: not sure I explained fair enough in my post. I need to extract value of "post" column in table "rating" going by columns "user" and "ratingtype" and use to value to filter table of Post.

Comment: @Augis: but you are later going to retrieve the `Post` objects itself? Then it is more efficient and elegant to work with `JOIN`s, and that is what the double underscores do.

Comment: @Augis: you thus don't need to extract the value of a column. Django can follow relations in *reverse*.

Comment: thanks a lot, took some time to realise what you were saying, but you are right, many thanks!